# tikzpicture csv unwanted lines

Tags: pgfplots

I've got a problem with a `pgfplots` plot, namely, I wanted to draw a transistor chart from given .csv file, and it works - partially - `pgfplots` adds unwanted lines for me:

[image: Unwanted lines from end of each line back to 0]

I just wonder how can I get rid of those?

Here's my latex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$V_{CE}$ [V]},
    ylabel={$I(V_{CE})$ [mA]}
]

\addplot table [x=a, y=b, col sep=comma,mark=none] {csv/chwyj.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here's the .csv file if needed: [csv](https://files.fm/u/x2qc59nj)

^^File's too big to add it here as a text, sorry for inconvenience..

Is there any setting that would cut those additional lines? It would be great if someone could help me with it..

Here's small sample from .csv file that causes the problem.

```
a,b
  4.980000000000e+000  ,1.200000173412e-003  
  4.990000000000e+000  ,1.200000173412e-003  
  5.000000000000e+000  ,1.200000173412e-003  
  0.000000000000e+000  ,-2.957746801258e-006  
  1.000000000000e-002  ,1.538370706839e-004  
  2.000000000000e-002  ,3.506754583213e-004  
  3.000000000000e-002  ,5.848283763044e-004  
  4.000000000000e-002  ,8.461686084047e-004  
  5.000000000000e-002  ,1.117891748436e-003  
  6.000000000000e-002  ,1.380363013595e-003  
  7.000000000000e-002  ,1.616477151401e-003  
  8.000000000000e-002  ,1.815661205910e-003  
  9.000000000000e-002  ,1.974782207981e-003  
  1.000000000000e-001  ,2.096456009895e-003  
  1.100000000000e-001  ,2.186418743804e-003  
  1.200000000000e-001  ,2.251294208691e-003  
  1.300000000000e-001  ,2.297240775079e-003  
  1.400000000000e-001  ,2.329366048798e-003  
  1.500000000000e-001  ,2.351626986638e-003  
  1.600000000000e-001  ,2.366956556216e-003  
  1.700000000000e-001  ,2.377467462793e-003  
  1.800000000000e-001  ,2.384653314948e-003  
  1.900000000000e-001  ,2.389556029812e-003  
  2.000000000000e-001  ,2.392896451056e-003  
  2.100000000000e-001  ,2.395170275122e-003  
  2.200000000000e-001  ,2.396716969088e-003  
  2.300000000000e-001  ,2.397768665105e-003  
  2.400000000000e-001  ,2.398483688012e-003  
  2.500000000000e-001  ,2.398969605565e-003  
  2.600000000000e-001  ,2.399299759418e-003  
  2.700000000000e-001  ,2.399524208158e-003  
  2.800000000000e-001  ,2.399676712230e-003  
  2.900000000000e-001  ,2.399780089036e-003  
  3.000000000000e-001  ,2.399850636721e-003  
  3.100000000000e-001  ,2.399898367003e-003  
  3.200000000000e-001  ,2.399930730462e-003  
  3.300000000000e-001  ,2.399952849373e-003  
  3.400000000000e-001  ,2.399967750534e-003  
  3.500000000000e-001  ,2.399977995083e-003  
  3.600000000000e-001  ,2.399984980002e-003  
  3.700000000000e-001  ,2.399989636615e-003  
  3.800000000000e-001  ,2.399992896244e-003  
  3.900000000000e-001  ,2.399994991720e-003  
  4.000000000000e-001  ,2.399996388704e-003  
  4.100000000000e-001  ,2.399997552857e-003  
  4.200000000000e-001  ,2.399998251349e-003  
  4.300000000000e-001  ,2.399998717010e-003  
  4.400000000000e-001  ,2.399998949841e-003  
  4.500000000000e-001  ,2.399999182671e-003  
  4.600000000000e-001  ,2.399999415502e-003  
  4.700000000000e-001  ,2.399999415502e-003  
  4.830000000000e+000  ,2.400000113994e-003  
  4.840000000000e+000  ,2.400000113994e-003  
  4.850000000000e+000  ,2.400000113994e-003  
  4.860000000000e+000  ,2.400000113994e-003  
  4.870000000000e+000  ,2.400000113994e-003  
  4.880000000000e+000  ,2.400000113994e-003  
  4.890000000000e+000  ,2.400000113994e-003  
  4.900000000000e+000  ,2.400000113994e-003  
  4.910000000000e+000  ,2.400000113994e-003  
  4.920000000000e+000  ,2.400000113994e-003  
  4.930000000000e+000  ,2.400000113994e-003  
  4.940000000000e+000  ,2.400000113994e-003  
  4.950000000000e+000  ,2.400000113994e-003  
  4.960000000000e+000  ,2.400000113994e-003  
  4.970000000000e+000  ,2.400000113994e-003  
  4.980000000000e+000  ,2.400000113994e-003  
  4.990000000000e+000  ,2.400000113994e-003  
  5.000000000000e+000  ,2.400000113994e-003  
  0.000000000000e+000  ,-4.436620201886e-006  
  1.000000000000e-002  ,2.307556278538e-004  
  2.000000000000e-002  ,5.260132020339e-004  
  3.000000000000e-002  ,8.772426517680e-004  
  4.000000000000e-002  ,1.269252970815e-003
```

**EDIT**
There's proper chart which I'm trying to get (without dashed lines)
[image: in addition]

**EDIT**
I solved that problem.. but not the way I wanted to. Namely - .csv I got had multiple characteristics as a whole inside, and that caused the problem. What I did was manually cut every 500 points from each characteristics and saved it into each separate .csv files.

```
\newcounter{thenumber}
\forloop{thenumber}{1}{\value{thenumber} < 6}{
\addplot +[mark=none,color=blue] table [x=a, y=b, col sep=comma] {csv/chwyj\arabic{thenumber}.csv};
}
```

Now it works as I intented.. but still - it gives me more work to do.

[image: Working chart]

Comment: you should add your `chwyj.csv`. without it we can reproduce 't compile your MWE.

Comment: I added .csv file below the latex code

Comment: Please don't use external links. Add .csv data as text.

Comment: Ah, I see.. but it's quite huge - that's why I added it as a file.

Just checked - it's too large to write as text here.

Comment: @Endlesik, make it shorter for this example, but long enough that will show your problem.

Comment: Same result with `matplotlib`, the problem is likely the data file itself, that it isn't properly sorted.

Comment: Probably you're right.. The data came from PSpice simulation - can I done anything to get it right?

Comment: It's perfectly fine to self-answer a question, so please do that rather than editing an answer into the question post.

Answer (score 1):

I solved that problem.. but not the way I wanted to. Namely - .csv I got had multiple characteristics as a whole inside, and that caused the problem. What I did was manually cut every 500 points from each characteristics and saved it into each separate .csv files.

```
\newcounter{thenumber}
\forloop{thenumber}{1}{\value{thenumber} < 6}{
\addplot +[mark=none,color=blue] table [x=a, y=b, col sep=comma] {csv/chwyj\arabic{thenumber}.csv};
}
```

Now it works as I intented.. but still - it gives me more work to do.

[image: the perfect chart]